# Specific character in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with all employee details including email addresses

Is there any specific query via which I can find the length of the email addresses till the letter '@' is encountered?

> if the email address is azxcde@asas.com, then I want to extract the
>   azxcde part of the email.

Comment: I am working on sq server management studio, does that answer your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select 
Left(EmailColumnName,CharIndex('@',EmailColumnName)-1) as UserName 
from tableName
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/706af/2)

Comment: what is the '-1' at the end of the command for?

Comment: You can find a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/706af/2

Comment: @Naga CharIndex return the postion in of charter and left select it number of chater from left so to select only username not '@' i subtract -1 from charindex. if you dont it will add @ also in last

Comment: @Gidil thanks sql fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative version using SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(EmailColumnName,0,CHARINDEX(' ',EmailColumnName)) as UserName
FROM tablName
```